# Not able to perform any calls to nifi using nipyapi

Tags: python, apache-nifi, nipyapi

I am trying to work with nipyapi but any function I run gives me an error.

Here's the code for config :

```
import nipyapi
nipyapi.config.nifi_config.host = 'https://localhost:8443/nifi-api'
nipyapi.config.nifi_config.username = 'admin'
nipyapi.config.nifi_config.password = 'qwertyadmin1'
nipyapi.config.registry_config.host = 'https://localhost:18080/nifi-registry'
```

The code which is giving error :

```
root = nipyapi.canvas.get_root_pg_id()
```

I get a bunch of warnings and then the error,
Here's an example warning :

```
2022-03-24 23:28:16,876 WARNING Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('\x15\x03\x03\x00\x02\x02P'))': /nifi-api/flow/process-groups/root/status
2022-03-24 23:28:16,876 WARNING Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('\x15\x03\x03\x00\x02\x02P'))': /nifi-api/flow/process-groups/root/status
```

The error :

```
MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8443): Max retries exceeded with url: /nifi-api/flow/process-groups/root/status (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('\x15\x03\x03\x00\x02\x02P')))
```

P.S. I am trying to create a user-friendly interface which allows users with no knowledge of nifi, to build dynamic pipelines based on their requirement. Would Also love to hear your thoughts whether it would be possible with nipyapi or not. I am optimistic though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Try to use connection from
https://chamila.dev/blog/2021-07-18_ci-cd-for-apache-nifi-02-automation-with-nipyapi/
It works for me.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.